# Why does Pubmed entrez tool for pmid 2 pmcid give weird results

Tags: bioinformatics, pubmed

I was writing an rspec for a Ruby script that includes converting from PMid to PMCid, using this api.

Calling it like [this](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/utils/entrezpmc.cgi?1279666) works fine:

```
PubMedId             => PMCId               
1279666              => 50267
```

But I was writing a spec and wanted a failing call, like when someone passes in a string instead of a number. So I tried [this](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/utils/entrezpmc.cgi?foobar):

```
PubMedId             => PMCId               
foobar               => 320759,320760,322131,322132,323033,323035,323115,323117...[599027 total PMCids]
```

This returns 599027 PMCids!

I just checked the [reverse service](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/utils/pmcentrez.cgi?50267):

```
PMCId                => PubMedId            
50267                => 1279666
```

Ant the [call](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/utils/pmcentrez.cgi?foobar):

```
PMCId                => PubMedId            
foobar               =>
```

Looks OK.

Does anyone know if this is the correct (and documented) behaviour for the PMid to PMCid service?

Interestingly, when I [reverse looked-up](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/utils/pmcentrez.cgi?320760,320759,320760,322131,322132,323033,323035,323115,323117) some of the PMCids returned by 'foobar', they are all showing a matching PMid of zero:

```
PMCId                => PubMedId            
320760               => 0                   
320759               => 0                   
320760               => 0                   
322131               => 0                   
322132               => 0                   
323033               => 0                   
323035               => 0                   
323115               => 0                   
323117               => 0
```

Comment: Giving it any string appears to make it return all ~599000 results, but in a randomly determined order.